# Check in luggage at two different airports

Tags: luggage

I have a flight from the United States to Istanbul, and I will stay there for a couple days. Then I'll go to Venice from Istanbul and after 11 days I will leave Italy from Rome. My return flight from Rome to  the US has a 2.5-hour layover in Istanbul.

If I leave my luggage with baggage custody at the Istanbul airport and check in one bag in Rome, can I check in another baggage, which will be in Istanbul airport, during the layover? Does the airline allow me to check another bag in Istanbul?

Comment: Generally this is not permissible.

Comment: In my experience, it is not a problem, provided you do not exceed your total luggage allowance.

Comment: ... and what did the airline say, in the call that you surely have made to them before asking here on the site? :-(

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful. For several reasons.

- First, you'd have to enter Turkey again (ie pass Immigration), pick up this extra piece of luggage, go to the check in counters, check it in, and go back to the transit area (security checks, immigration, go to gate, secondary security check). All that in two hours.
- If you have one ticket, one one airline, Rome back to the US, via Istanbul (I suppose via Turkish airlines), your check-in is final in Rome, and you're not supposed to check in again along the way. Depending on the country, you might not even be allowed to leave the transit area.
- I am not sure there is even a luggage storage facility in Istanbul, especially not after the terrorist attack there. You should check.

All in all, I doubt that this is possible. But you know what? Instead of asking here, you should talk to the airline. They have the knowledge and answer.

Comment: Do you have a source for the second bullet point? Although I try to avoid checking luggage altogether, certainly I have checked luggage in part way through journeys before a few times. Often useful if you have a layover and need your bag for the layover but not later.

Comment: Only my own experience of 13+ years traveling internationally :-)

Comment: Security reasons are also very strict. I doubt you can flight in US if you doesn't know what there is in your baggage (storing is not considered safe).

Comment: Your check-in as a passenger is one thing, and carrying a bag is another thing. Now, you could say airlines won't permit adding a bag after the number of bags has been "finalized", but your second bullet point does not necessitate that to be the case.