# At transit or layover, have checked-in luggage transferred to the next airline without passenger retrieval and re-drop

Tags: luggage, layovers, check-in, covid-19, stopovers

Is there any way to book two connected flights (from different airlines; each one on a unrelated website):

- without passing via 3rd party agency (online or not)
- still being able to **organize the luggage transfer from one flight to the other**
- **without needing to leave the transit area**, to pass the border control just to get your baggage from Airline-A and then check it in again with Airline-B, and having to pass the border control again?

From my little experience I know the luggage transfer is managed directly from the airport; but that this happens automatically just if the [**PNR (Passenger name record)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger_name_record) is the same for the two booking.

*How can a private humble human being achieve that?*

Can it be organised calling the specific airlines? (usually just the first airline checks-in the luggage)  Or by calling the layover airport? Or using a special system?

I think the main matter is to make one airline aware of the following one (that of course is not automatic, when booking separately on different websites).

From [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/101757/72133) looks like it should be possible, without passing from a 3rd party *CRS (Computer reservation system)*.

---

I think this information might be really useful to many, in these times of COVID-19/Coronavirus, with really few options for people to repatriate, and often with agencies not having viable routes.

Comment: The answer you link to has nothing to do with the scenario you are asking about.

Comment: @Kamafeather I tried this with Condor / Lufthansa separate booking but was refused https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151992/will-condor-through-check-baggage-onto-lufthansa-flights

Comment: It all depends on the airlines. I managed to get luggage interlined between two flights that were on separate bookings. The first flight was with SWISS, the second one with TAP. Both are Star Alliance, so this is maybe why they did it. I did have to ask for it though.

Comment: The first thing that needs to happen is that both airlines need to have an interlining agreement, valid at the given airport. Then the first airline has to accept to check you through. Some alliances will allow you to do that. In most cases though it’s quite difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The process of having multiple airlines handle your bags is called "interlining". In order for that to happen the airlines MUST have an interlining agreement in place. This agreement manages cost,tracking, liability, data exchange, etc. of the baggage transfer.

All airlines that are in the same alliance do have interlining agreement, but interlining typically extends a significantly past the alliance. However, the information is not easy to find.

If there is not interline agreement, there is no baggage transfer.

If there is an interline agreement, it's possible that a baggage transfer could happen, but this depends a lot on how the ticket is being booked.

> Can a private humble human being achieve that?

Not unless you book it as a single ticket. Your best shot is to call a knowledgeable travel agent, they have access to data & information that you don't, plus a (hopefully) lot of experience. This will cost you extra, so you need to decide what it's worth to you.

Comment: As a "private humble human being" you can achieve that. First call the airline you booked the first ticket with to ask if that is possible. Then when checking in have the ticket nr. for the second ticket handy.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, this cannot happen. You might be able to contact the airline/airport in advance and they might do this for you, but I doubt it.

The only other reason is if both of the airlines are members of the same group, e.g. Oneworld, then they could have this done for you.

Comment: If the airlines are in the same alliance then you can usually book the flights on a single booking anyway, via code sharing. Not always though.